# Using seq in R with varying step

Tags: r, seq

I want to create the following sequence in R: ((2^1)/1, (2^2)/2, ..., (2^25)/25) using the `seq` function and not another function. Can somebody help me?

I also know how to do it without the `seq`, just by typing:

```
n <- 1:25
y <- (2^n)/n
y
```

Answer (score 1):

Very easy, why sec?

```
x<-seq(1, 25)
2^x/x
```

Comment: because my paper says I need to use seq function to do it

Comment: Ok,  so you can create whatever x

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want:

```
 y <- (2^ seq(1, 25)) /seq(1, 25)
```